# Change color depending on background jQuery

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

Is there any way to recognize the background color behind the logo and set a class dark or light on body from it?

I've tried to make a sloppy dummy on the problem I'm having (I'm terrible at JS). The main idea I had was to set a class dark or light on body depending on the background color of the active section. This obviously doesn't work out quite well when sections aren't full height. When a section with dynamic height exist my whole idea gets demolished.

Do you guys have any idea of how to solve this?

Have a look at my Fiddle for a hopefully better understanding:
https://jsfiddle.net/Bondra/9jqvm6n6/7/

```
HTML
        <header>
      <div class="logo">
        Logo
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="fullpage">
        <div id="section1" class="section light" data-anchor="secondPage">
          <h1>Content 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="section2" class="section dark fp-auto-height" data-anchor="firstPage">
          <h1>Content 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="section3" class="section light" data-anchor="secondPage">
          <h1>Content 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage'],
    menu: '#menu',
    onLeave: function() {
      $('body').toggleClass('dark');
    }
  });
```

CSS

```
        h1 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .fp-auto-height.fp-section,
    .fp-auto-height .fp-slide,
    .fp-auto-height .fp-tableCell {
      height: auto !important;
    }

    ol,
    ul {
      list-style: none outside none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    header {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px;
      top: 50px;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    header div {
      border: 2px solid #000;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .section {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #section1 {
      background-color: #eaeaea;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #section2 {
      background-color: #5E1062;
      color: white;
      padding: 100px 0;
    }

    #section3 {
      background-color: #eaeaea;
    }

    .dark .logo {
      border-color: white;
      color: white;
    }
```

Comment: so add or remove a class active depending on what section you are on/where the scroll is on and then switch the light/dark accordingly.. i don't really see the problem??

Comment: Yes but when scrolling down to the second slide, which isn't a full height section the logo turns white (yes, it does what it's intended to do because it's now the active one). But I would rather have it black until it really reaches a spot where the background is dark. It looks good when scrolling from bottom to top, but wierd in the other direction.

Comment: do a calc() on the top and set a new top in jquery

Comment: did you get this sorted?